# getting error in sqlite Update in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

i am getting error in the sqlite updation,here the query is correctly given, but the value is not updating.here i need to update the description value Where the given place, Below i add my code please help me

```
-(void) update:(NSString *)filePath withName:(NSString *)place description:(NSString*)description
{
    sqlite3* db = NULL;
    int rc=0;
     sqlite3_stmt* stmt =NULL;

rc = sqlite3_open_v2([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
if (SQLITE_OK != rc)
{
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSLog(@"Failed to open db connection");
}
else
{
    NSString * query  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE  places SET description=%@ WHERE place=%@",description,place];

    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [place UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [description UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    NSLog(@"query %@",query);
    char * errMsg;
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, [query UTF8String] ,NULL,&stmt,&errMsg);
    if(SQLITE_OK != rc)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to insert record  rc:%d, msg=%s",rc,errMsg);
    }
    else{
    NSLog(@"Sucessfully updated");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
 }
}
```

Table Creation

```
-(int) createTable:(NSString*) filePath
{
    sqlite3* db = NULL;
    int rc=0;
NSLog(@"create");
rc = sqlite3_open_v2([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
if (SQLITE_OK != rc)
{
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSLog(@"Failed to open db connection");
}
else
{
    char * query ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS places ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,place TEXT ,locationname TEXT,time TEXT,description TEXT,notifyTime TEXT,radius TEXT,lat DOUBLE,lon DOUBLE ,notify TEXT,selection INTEGER)";
    char * errMsg;
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query,NULL,NULL,&errMsg);

    if(SQLITE_OK != rc)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create table rc:%d, msg=%s",rc,errMsg);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Sucessfully Created ");
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
}
return rc;
```

}

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? Which code path does it take? Are the description and place variables what you expect them to be? What if you copy-paste the query into a command-line? Does it do what you expect?

Comment: getting error message "no such column"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ...check db is whether it is opened or not and change this code...

```
 -(void) update:(NSString *)filePath withName:(NSString *)place description:(NSString*)description
    {
        sqlite3* db = NULL;
        int rc=0;
        sqlite3_stmt* stmt =NULL;

        rc = sqlite3_open_v2([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE , NULL);
        if (SQLITE_OK != rc)
        {
            sqlite3_close(db);
            NSLog(@"Failed to open db connection");
        }
        else
        {
            /*
             NSString  *strMQueryupdate=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"update br set TOTAL='%@',QUTY='%@' WHERE PID='%@'",[@(total )stringValue],[@(lblQtn )stringValue],produdId];
             */

          NSString * query  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE  places SET description='%@' WHERE place='%@'",description,place];
            const char *sql = [query UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, & stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"update fails");
            }
            else
            {
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [place UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [description UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                int success = sqlite3_step(stmt);
                sqlite3_reset(stmt);
                if (success == SQLITE_ERROR)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"update success");

                }
                sqlite3_finalize(update_statement);
                sqlite3_close(db);
            }
    }
```

Comment: check your query.the place and description should be same with db table column name

Comment: add quotation in query and check..i have edited answer

Comment: While this likely compiles and runs, it does not use placeholder values and so presents a potential security problem.

Answer (score 1):

First open the DB connection.
Then write below code.

```
               NSString * query  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE  places SET description=%@ WHERE place=%@",description,place];
               SQL=[NSString stringWithString:query];
                sqlite3_stmt *insert_statement=nil;

                if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [SQL UTF8String], -1, &insert_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
                    //NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                    NSLog(@"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                }

                int result=sqlite3_step(insert_statement);
                sqlite3_finalize(insert_statement);
```

and then close the DB connection

Answer (score 0):

You're using prepared statements incorrectly. You hard-code the values in a string (a bad idea) and then setting the placeholder values -- which makes no sense as there are no placeholders in your SQL. Try something like:

```
NSString * query  = @"UPDATE  places SET description= ? WHERE place= ?";

sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [place UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [description UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

The reason you don't want to include the values directly in the query string: imagine someone passing in a value for place like "London'; drop table places;". (Not sure if that'll work but it should give you some idea of the kind of mischief that a user could get up to.)